# Using jQuery in Symfony2 php template

Tags: php, jquery, symfony

I am trying to do the embed multiple forms trick with Symfony2.  I have followed the  instructions in [The Book - collection Field Type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and [The Cookbook - How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html), but can't seem to get it to work.

I think part of the problem is that I am not very familiar with javascript or JQuery and these instructions assume full understanding (e.g. "To make things simple, we'll use jQuery and assume you have it included somewhere on your page.").  Also, I need for my templates to be written in php not twig, and I have not yet found an example of this done with a php template.

Here's what I've done so far...

My main form class:

```
class StudyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('studyName', null, array('label'=> 'Study Name:'))
            ->add('participants', 'collection', array(
            'type'=> new ParticipantType(), 
            'allow_add'=>true,
            'by_reference'=>false
         ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'study';
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) 
{
  return array(
      'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Study',
  );
}
```

My embedded form class:

```
class ParticipantType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('participantId','text', array('label'=>'Participant ID'))
        ->add('dOB', 'date', array(
            'label'=>'D.O.B.', 
            'years'=>range(date('Y'), 1932),
            'required'=>false
         ))
        ->add('gender', 'choice', array(
            'label'=>'Gender',
            'choices'=>array('F'=>'F', 'M'=>'M'),
            'required'=>false
        ))
        ->add('dateEnteredStudy', 'date', array(
            'label'=>'Date entered trial', 
            'years'=>range(date('Y'), 1990),
            'required'=>false
        ))
        ->add('dateCompletedStudy', 'date', array(
            'label'=>'Date completed trial', 
            'years'=>range(date('Y'), 1990),
            'required'=>false
        ))
        ;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'participant';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options) 
    {
      return array(
          'data_class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Participant',
      );
    }
}
```

My base.html.php template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title><?php $view['slots']->output('title', 'My title') ?></title>
    <?php $view['slots']->output('stylesheets') ?>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('favicon.ico') ?>" />
</head>
<body>
    <?php $view['slots']->start('mainMenu')  ?>
        <!--lots of menu items here -->
    <?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>

    <?php $view['slots']->start('javascripts') ?>
        <script src="<?php echo $view['assets']->getUrl('/js/jquery-1.7.1.js') ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>

    <?php $view['slots']->output('mainMenu') ?>
    <?php $view['slots']->output('body') ?>
    <?php $view['slots']->output('javascripts') ?>
</body>
```

My study.html.php template:

```
 <?php $view->extend('MyBundle::base.html.php') ?>

    <?php $view['slots']->start('body') ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('study', array('id'=>$entity->getId()))?>" method="post" <?php echo $view['form']->enctype($form) ?>>
    <ul id="multi-participant" data-prototype="<?php echo $view->escape($view['form']->row($form['participants']->get('prototype'))) ?>">
    </ul>

    <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form) ?>
    <h2>Study</h2>
    <?php echo $view['form']->label($form['studyName'])?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form['studyName'])?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->widget($form['studyName'])?>

    <h3>Participants in this study</h3>
    <ul id="participants">
        <?php foreach($form['participants'] as $participant): ?>
            <li><?php echo $view['form']->row($participant) ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" id="add-another-participant">Add participant</a>

  </form> 
  <?php $view['slots']->stop() ?>

   <script type='text/javascript'>
      // keep track of how many participant fields have been rendered
      var participantCount = document.getElementById("participants").length;
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery('#add-another-participant').click(function() {
              var participantList = jQuery('#multi-participant');

              var newParticipant = participantList.attr('data-prototype');
              newParticipant = newParticipant.replace(/\$\$name\$\$/g, participantCount);
              participantCount++;

              var newLi = jQuery('<li>,</li>').html(newParticipant);
              newLi.appendTo(jQuery('#multi-participant'));

              return false;
          });
      });

    </script>
```

My page displays correctly with editable forms for all existing Participants for the Study and with the "Add Participant" link present at the bottom.  However, when I click the link, nothing happens.

I've followed the instructions as closely as I can, so I'm hoping someone can pinpoint the error and set me on the right track. If you do provide an answer, please be explicit because I really don't know what I'm doing re:javascript  (I will learn it eventually, but need to solve this problem quickly).

Many thanks

Comment: You are biting off quite a bit here.  Start with the basics and just get jquery to load.  Plenty of into cookbooks on doing that.  Then I would suggest getting the cookbook examples to work using twig.  Just implement exactly as the example shows.  Then you the foundation from which you can expand and convert to a php template.

Comment: Any reason you didn't want to use twig?

Comment: @Flukey I was resisting Twig because there are so many other things I need to learn (having only barely mastered Symfony 1.4 with php templates and now moving to Symfony2). I am now in the process of converting my template to twig (without success - look out for another question soon)

Comment: Consider giving twig a try.  Makes doing templates much easier to understand.

Comment: @Cerad I took your advice and found it wasn't as difficult to pick up Twig as I expected.  There is still a learning curve, but the amount of advice available should make it easier.